# How to determine if two pandas Series are within a given time interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 `pandas.Series` with datetime datatype.

First series : `['2017-12-31 16:00:00-08:00', '2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00', '2017-12-31 18:00:00-08:00']`

Second series : `['2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00', None, '2017-12-31 18:00:10-08:00']`

I want to check if the two series are equal with the following condition :

- when comparing a time with None, it should output True
- when comparing two time, they must be within 10 mins apart. Otherwise, output False

Expected output : `[False, True, True]`

```
def date_check(x, y):
    return (np.abs(x - y)) > timedelta(minutes=10)
```

it reaches an error : `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'NoneType'`

Answer (score 1):

- If the `pandas.Series` have been converted to a `datetime` format, they will not contain `None`, they will contain `NaT`, which leads me to think, the `Series` are not formatted as `datetime` objects.
- Given a `pandas.DataFrame` with two columns of dates
- Convert the columns to a datetime, with `pandas.to_datetime`
- `.fillna` on column `b`, which will ensure the time difference is < 10 minutes
- If both columns are `None`, fill them with `pandas.Timedelta(0)`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

a = ['2017-12-31 16:00:00-08:00', '2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00', '2017-12-31 18:00:00-08:00', None]
b = ['2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00', None, '2017-12-31 18:00:10-08:00', None]

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})

# convert columns to datetime format
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

                          a                         b
0 2017-12-31 16:00:00-08:00 2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00
1 2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00                       NaT
2 2017-12-31 18:00:00-08:00 2017-12-31 18:00:10-08:00
3                       NaT                       NaT

# fillna in column b with values from column a
df.b = df.b.fillna(df.a)

# if both columns are None, fillna with Timedelta(0)
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))

                           a                          b
0  2017-12-31 16:00:00-08:00  2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00
1  2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00  2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00
2  2017-12-31 18:00:00-08:00  2017-12-31 18:00:10-08:00
3            0 days 00:00:00            0 days 00:00:00

# function
def date_check(x, y):
    return (np.abs(x - y)) < timedelta(minutes=10)


# function call
date_check(df.a, df.b)
[out]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

# add a column to the dataframe
df['time_diff'] = np.abs(df.a - df.b) < pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)

                           a                          b  time_diff
0  2017-12-31 16:00:00-08:00  2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00      False
1  2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00  2017-12-31 17:00:00-08:00       True
2  2017-12-31 18:00:00-08:00  2017-12-31 18:00:10-08:00       True
3            0 days 00:00:00            0 days 00:00:00       True
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't perform the operations on `NoneTypes` so just handle separately with a try/except block.

```
def date_check(x, y):
    try:
        return (np.abs(x - y)) > timedelta(minutes=10)
    except:
        return True
```